# How i put button click counter inside listview adapter

Tags: listview, android-listview, xamarin.android, onclicklistener

hi iam still beginner in xamarin android :(
i make listview with a button click that when i click button i will count click and shown in button.text but i cant handle click as well

here is my adapter GetView code :

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            var item = items[position];
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_ticket_view, null);
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.maintxt).Text = item.maintitle;
            view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtthwab).Text = item.thwab;

            var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
             button1.Text = (item.counter).ToString();
         }
```

i make button1 take start value form item.counter and start counting 
i.e item.counter=10 from class 
when click will 11,12,13,..etc
best regard

Answer (score 0):

you could try this :

```
class YourAdapter : BaseAdapter, View.IOnClickListener
    {

        private Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        int[] item;  //this is the data in my code ,you should replace your own data

    public YourAdapter(int[] value)  // the parameter use your own data
        {

            //copy your data into the dictionary
            item = value;
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
            {
                dictionary.Add(i,item[i].ToString());
            }
        }

public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.list_ticket_view, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.maintxt).Text = item.maintitle;
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtthwab).Text = item.thwab;

        var button1 = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        button1.Text = dictionary[position];
        button1.Tag = position;
        button1.SetOnClickListener(this);
        return convertView;
     }
}
 public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            var button = v as Button;
            int count = int.Parse(button.Text) + 1;
            button.Text = count.ToString();
            dictionary[(int) v.Tag] = count.ToString();
        }
```

let your `adapter` implement `View.IOnClickListener` e.g ：

```
class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter ,View.IOnClickListener
```

Comment: i try but i get this two error holder&integer : Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0103 The name 'holder' does not exist in the current context & Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS0103 The name 'Integer' does not exist in the current context

Comment: i have updated the answer ,the code used to run in my demo, so now you should be able to use it

Comment: ok its work but counting not effective sometimes count by1 second view count randomly .. i.e first view count 10,24,83.. ,second view count 10,11,12..

Comment: It is my mistake. Listview nested Button will cause data disorder if it is written like this. I have updated the answer and hope it can help you !

Comment: I recommend that you use holder to duplicate the layout when you use the listview

Comment: u r amazing man thnx bro, but still one thing more i can't find out the answer, when i scroll down and back to up the value change to not hold at same. for example, i count first view to 10 then scroll to down and back up valve not holding at 10

Comment: Since your data source has not changed, the data will still be loaded after returning, so you need to create a new collection to store the data after clicking.I will update the answer, you could do like this, if it helps you, please mark it, thank you !

Comment: sorry man but still get error at line : button1.Text = dictionary[position];  
 not open emulator                                                                                            Unhandled Exception:

System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key '0' was not present in the dictionary. occurred

Comment: Do you copy data into the "Dictionary" in the “adapter” constructor? I added comments in the code for the answer

Comment: Like 15 points to vote . if helpful ,you could mark it ,thank you !